# how to create a summary in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a holiday planner.
For  a month - July
I would like to create a dashboard where a user is provided with a a drop down which allows them to select week wise data
Query: How can I achieve this
Once I select the date, it should reflect the total no of employees available during that week

[image]

Comment: have you looked at countifs()? that may do what you want.

Comment: Where you will select date? Use `from date` and `to date` then `Countifs()`.

Comment: I have an additional worksheet, where there I am planning to provide an option to select start and end dates.....

Comment: There are subtotals, pivot tables, sumif(), countif(), sumifs(), countifs(), ..., plenty of features in Excel.